# Running an exe without calling "wine" cmd

Tags: wine

I would like wine to automatically run exe's without having to call wine everytime I have to execute the cmd.

so instead of typing out `"wine progarm.exe"` I would call `"program.exe`

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. What version is it?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04, sorry still new to this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install special [`wine-binfmt`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/wine-binfmt) package to *Register Wine as the interpreter for Windows executables* by

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine-binfmt
```

then set executable bit for needed exe-file by `chmod +x program.exe` and then run it as `./program.exe`.
To allow its run via `program.exe` you have to add its full-path to the `$PATH` environment variable.

---

Note: if you get `run-detectors: unable to find an interpreter for ./program.exe`, then run `sudo update-binfmts --import /usr/share/binfmts/wine` and retry.