# Can I run bat file in Ubuntu? How?

Tags: networking

How to run in Ubuntu using bat file?

> #### Setup with a start.bat file
>
> Once you download the file from Assets, unzip it and in the same
> folder as t-rex.exe, create a start.bat file with the contents:
>
> ```
> t-rex.exe -a ethash -o ethash.unmineable.com:3333 -u COIN:YOURADDRESS.WORKER_NAME -p x
> pause
> ```

But how?

Comment: Even if you were able to get the `*.bat` file to run in Ubuntu, how would you get the `t-rex.exe` file to run? After solving your 1st problem, you would run into another problem.

Comment: What do you mean ? What command i use for running ? $ or # in Ubuntu ?

Comment: And i am not able to run yet ! Its just saying run the bat file but i want to run via coding so which command should i need to start this bat file ?

Comment: What do you get if you run `file t-rex.exe`

Comment: I didn't but how to start it will be great !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running an exe without calling "wine" cmd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310977/running-an-exe-without-calling-wine-cmd)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to install windows software in linux.  This won't work.  You have to get a linux version of the program if you want to install it in linux.

For alternatives, see [How can I install Windows software or games?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988/how-can-i-install-windows-software-or-games)

Comment: Nha i just trying to run a file in Ubuntu or Linux but i did know command to start for bat

Comment: That's a windows file, you can't run it in linux.

Comment: Then how to to run in Ubuntu

Comment: T-Rex ubuntu https://t-rex.tileserver.ch/doc/setup/